# java.lang.SecurityException trying to read from Android Contacts URI

Tags: android, permissions, contacts

I am trying to read Contact names, phone #'s, and emails from the `ContactsContract` URI, and I am getting a `SecurityException` when I try to run the program.  I have set the permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="edu.smumn.cs394"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    **<uses-permission android:name="android.pemission.READ_CONTACTS"/>**
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ReadPhoneNumbers"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`
```

The following is the application code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);       
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
 //[...] Work through data here`
```

I get a security exception on the last line (`resolver.query()`):

```
`03-08 07:41:40.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 07:41:40.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.smumn.cs394/edu.smumn.cs394.ReadPhoneNumbers}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=416, uid=10037 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
[...]
03-08 07:41:40.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=416, uid=10037 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
[...]
03-08 07:41:40.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(416):     at edu.smumn.cs394.ReadPhoneNumbers.onCreate(ReadPhoneNumbers.java:30)
```

[...]`

I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: You have a Syntaxis error in your AndroidManifest.xml file. In the line **<uses-permission android:name="android.pemission.READ_CONTACTS"/>** android.permission is written wrong without R and should looks like "permission" instead of "pemission".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you add it outside of the application tag.  While developing for a target platform of 2.3.3 using Eclipse on Ubuntu, I had permission failures in the log file that indicated I needed this exact line while working on something similar.  It wasn't until I moved the *uses-permission...READ_CONTACTS* line to outside the application tag that things worked.

Comment: +1: This was the case for me also on Windows 7 system (targeting api v10 to v19). I had added the permission using the GUI and that appded inside <application>  tag. I replaced that with <uses-permission> tag.

Answer (score 17):

***Requesting Permissions at Run Time***

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

If the permission you need to add isn't listed under the normal permissions, you'll need to deal with "Runtime Permissions". Runtime permissions are permissions that are requested as they are needed while the app is running. These permissions will show a dialog to the user, similar to the following one:

[image]

The first step when adding a "Runtime Permission" is to add it to the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.codepath.androidpermissionsdemo" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Next, you'll need to initiate the permission request and handle the result. The following code shows how to do this in the context of an Activity, but this is also possible from within a Fragment.

```
// MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // In an actual app, you'd want to request a permission when the user performs an action
        // that requires that permission.
        getPermissionToReadUserContacts();
    }

    // Identifier for the permission request
    private static final int READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;

    // Called when the user is performing an action which requires the app to read the
    // user's contacts
    public void getPermissionToReadUserContacts() {
        // 1) Use the support library version ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) to avoid
        // checking the build version since Context.checkSelfPermission(...) is only available
        // in Marshmallow
        // 2) Always check for permission (even if permission has already been granted)
        // since the user can revoke permissions at any time through Settings
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // The permission is NOT already granted.
            // Check if the user has been asked about this permission already and denied
            // it. If so, we want to give more explanation about why the permission is needed.
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
            }

            // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
            // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    // Callback with the request from calling requestPermissions(...)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
        if (requestCode == READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Hello Steven the debug log trace tells you that you need
... requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

so just try something by editing the Manifest.xml like adding another permission, let see if its not correctly readed.

and check this line without **

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

---

dan

Answer (score 5):

with the api 23, permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.pemission.READ_CONTACTS"/>` dont work, change the api level in the emulator for api 22(lollipop) or lower

Comment: So whats the alternative?

Comment: Downgrade api shouldn't be a solution !!

Comment: The alternative is to code an explicit request permission for API 23+ as shown in the documentation, I also had to downgrade the targetVersion of my sdk to 22 to prevent doing such a tedious work

Comment: I am getting the same issue although I am on API 22. Any solutions please??

Answer (score 2):

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

EXAMPLE:

```
 //thisActivity is the running activity


if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
```

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html