# Android SecurityException: no permission to uri

Tags: android, security, securityexception

I try from my app to query content provider of an other app (not my app).
The provider in that app is defined with:

```
android:readPermission="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET" 
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
```

From my app i added the user permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to manifest file but i get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.* from ProcessRecord{427afe60 29052:*/u0a72} (pid=29052, uid=10072) requires android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET or com.*.ACCESS
```

Does anyone have and idea?

Comment: please clean your project and run it.

Comment: Just go on for this link and check for this code,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233543/java-lang-securityexception-trying-to-read-from-android-contacts-uri][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233543/java-lang-securityexception-trying-to-read-from-android-contacts-uri

Comment: @Mehul1000 i clean the project... it's not working :(

Comment: @Najib Puthawala i have the permision in manifest file!

Answer (score 0):

You can't give your application BIND_APPWIDGET since that is a signature|system permission. See the [Android core resources manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) for more information.

Comment: this mean that i can not use this provider :|