# Unfortunately <App Name> has stopped. PLEASE READ: It's different, I promise

Tags: java, android

Right, So before you sigh please read.
I am a new amateur programmer and really require your help on this one.
I debug my app on a phone running 4.4.2 and it works all the time during debug, however when I disconnect the USB cable it says "Unfortunately, LSA has stopped" (I have even tried exporting it as a signed app and installing it on the phone.)
Here is the manifest file but if you require any other files please ask. Sorry if the answer to this is simplistic or if it already been answered (which i'm sure it hasn't.) Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lsa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Contents"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RevPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**edit**
I found this in the stack trace

```
12-04 18:57:59.165    4410-4465/lawnswood.lsa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: lawnswood.lsa, PID: 4410
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/profile/data from   pid=4410, uid=10186 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:464)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(Native Method)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please post the logcat stack trace. If you can get it to crash with the debug version (by unplugging the USB cable) that would be the better stack trace to post. If it only happens with the exported version, then try turning off ProGuard and see if that resolves the problem; if so, then there's a ProGuard configuration issue.

Comment: The logcat is the most important first piece but it's likely a threading issue if it works in debug

Comment: also some code could be of help

Comment: The logcat just ends with "Device disconnected" and ProGuard was never on. I can still post logcat if you think it could help.

Comment: That's your console output not the logcat

Comment: @codeMagic I edited the post and added the error from the logcat. Help would be apprciated.

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233543/java-lang-securityexception-trying-to-read-from-android-contacts-uri

Comment: "requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" - well, there ya go.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Sorry for my stupidity.

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/profile/data from   pid=4410, uid=10186 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

This says to me that you need to put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS">`into your android manifest, as you seem to be trying to read the contacts list but don't have permission. It may work while debugging as the debugging allows it to run without the permission, but I'm not certain.