# How we can avoid this security exception in android 5.1 for Note 5 devices

Tags: android, security, samsung-mobile

I'm making app on android and this application use the Read-contacts permission , but all Note 5 devices have this error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/77744444444 from pid=6345, uid=10231 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

I don't know how I can solve that I searched and read a lot all people say the same thing about Note 5 devices from Samsung !

Comment: Check if you have this permision on your manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233543/java-lang-securityexception-trying-to-read-from-android-contacts-uri

Comment: Yes it's at manifest , the application is working very good on all devices except Note 5 , This device can not read this permission I don't know why !